# How to load .dll file with header in python?

Tags: python-2.7, dll, header, ctypes

I am working on moving a program from MATLAB to python. In MATLAB it calls both the .dll file and the .h file. I cannot figure out how to link the two in python. I can import the .dll file with ctypes, but I cannot access the functions in the .dll. Does anyone understand the differences in .dll loading in MATLAB vs. python?

Specifically:

The code I am using to import is...

```
dll = ctypes.WinDLL("path")

attrib = dll.__getattribute__('name')
```

It returns that the attribute does not exist, but I know from the header file it does. Do I need to incorporate the header file to get the .dll to work?

Comment: I gather you're new to Python. You shouldn't call `__getattribute__` here. Either use `dll.name`, or if it isn't a valid identifier, use `getattr(lib, 'name')`.

Comment: As to the header, there's an old ctypesgen project to automate processing headers, but for the most part with ctypes you have to either manually define function prototypes and struct definitions, or write your own code to automate the process specific to your needs.  [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.org) is an alternative to ctypes that can parse C declarations, which may be easier and more reliable depending the complexity of the C library that you're using.